# Java: Sorting Map of Type Map<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, dictionary

I have a Map having an String as Key and an ArrayList as Value.
ArrayList is basically a list of four values linked to key somehow.

My sample data is :

```
String : [ArrayList<String>] 

"USA":    ["25", "5", "20", "4"]
"India":  ["15", "7", "8", "2"]
"Canada": ["29", "17", "8", "6"]
```

I need to sort this Map in descending order as per first value in ArrayList so it becomes like below:

```
"Canada": ["29", "17", "8", "6"]
"USA":    ["25", "5",  "20","4"]
"India":  ["15", "7",  "8", "2"]
```

I am trying below function, but its not working for ArrayList type Map value:

```
public class MapUtil
{
    public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
        sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
    {
        List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
            {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
            }
        } );

        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
        {
            result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this function to achieve what I need?

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the entire `ArrayList<String>` values, but you want to compare by the first value in each `ArrayList`.

You should do something like :

```
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> o1, Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> o2)
    {
        return (o1.getValue().get(0)).compareTo( o2.getValue().get(0) );
    }
```

Of course you should add null checks, in case o1.getValue() returns null or an empty list.

However, you should note that this would compare the values as Strings (in which, for example "5" > "23"), not numbers. If you want a numeric comparison, you should convert the Strings to integers, or store them as integers in the first place.

Comment: +1  
... but since the desired order is descending, the comparator has to do **o2.getValue().get(0).compareTo( o1.getValue().get(0) )**

I also recommend using **ArrayList** for *list* instead of **LinkedList**, as *Collections.sort()* will call *toArray()* on it, and **ArrayList** will perform it a bit quicker.

Comment: @Eran `get(0)` is not defined for type `V` obviously. Don't I need to change `V` to `ArrayList<V>` everywhere?

Comment: @foobar From the title and description of your question it seemed you wanted to sort a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`. I'm not sure how your code is related to what you are trying to achieve. You should implement a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: @Eran Thanks for your help. I have posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code as below to achieve my requirement.

Also had to change the Map value to `ArrayList< Integer>` for efficient sorting.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> sortByValue(Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map)
    {
        List<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>(
                map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>() 
                {
                    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> o1,Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> o2)
                    {
                        return (o2.getValue().get(0)).compareTo(o1.getValue().get(0));
                    }
                });

        Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : list) 
        {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
```